# F# function conciseness when generating random numbers

Tags: function, random, f#

Is there a reason why one writes the line:

```
(fun max -> rndGen.Next(max))
```

https://github.com/sebfia/OffLog/blob/master/Shared/Helpers.fs#L8

```
let NextRandom =
    let rndGen = new System.Random(int System.DateTime.Now.Ticks)
    (fun max -> rndGen.Next(max))
```

Instead of just declaring the param max upfront and calling `rndGen.Next(max)`, like this?

```
let NextRandom (max: int) =
    let rndGen = new System.Random(int System.DateTime.Now.Ticks)
    rndGen.Next(max)
```

Comment: Just run and see difference ;)

Comment: Hehe! To see the difference @FoggyFinder means, you have to run the second version multiple times. Unless enough time passes between calls, `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` may return the same value multiple times, due to its granularity, which can be surprisingly coarse. That aside, be wary of `System.Random`. It's not exactly a well-designed RNG... I get a bit of an eerie feeling when I see it used in serious work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is lifetime:

- In the first, `rndGen` is only seeded once and reused thereafter, and will live for the lifetime of the scope in which `NextRandom` is defined – if class-scope the lifetime of the class, or if module-scope the lifetime of the `AppDomain`.
- In the second, `rndGen` will be created – and seeded! – anew each time `NextRandom` is invoked.

The net effect is that if `NextRandom` is invoked repeatedly in rapid succession, the second version can (and very likely will) return the same "random" number multiple times in a row, making it effectively useless for many normal usecases e.g. initializing a collection of random numbers. However, unlike the first version, the second version has the advantage of being thread-safe.

Comment: thanks, so it is almost like the 1st version utilizes closure to only initialize rndGen once..?

Comment: @Porton : That's exactly what it's like – the returned lambda in the first version is the very epitome of a closure. :-]